# build a profile page in expressJS and handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

so i'm wondering how can i display  the actual user information on a page to a make a simple user profile page ?

i'm using passportJS and mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the frontend you'd want to make an AJAX/HTTP request for the user profile data. then you can render it however you see fit. I suggest starting with simple  tags or something. Your backend will need to serve the user profile data via an endpoint. like /api/user